# Spring boot application startup hangs on line "started bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger'"

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-gcp, spring-cloud-bus

I've decided `spring cloud config` + `spring cloud bus`. So I've implemented config server first:
full code base could be found here:

https://github.com/gredwhite/config-server-demo

But when I try to start it locally am not able to start the application. It hangs during strtup:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.5.RELEASE)

2020-03-16 11:28:21.799  INFO 19392 --- [           main] root_pack.ServerApplication              : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-03-16 11:28:22.227  WARN 19392 --- [           main] o.s.boot.actuate.endpoint.EndpointId     : Endpoint ID 'bus-env' contains invalid characters, please migrate to a valid format.
2020-03-16 11:28:22.400  WARN 19392 --- [           main] o.s.boot.actuate.endpoint.EndpointId     : Endpoint ID 'bus-refresh' contains invalid characters, please migrate to a valid format.
2020-03-16 11:28:22.570  INFO 19392 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=3539a615-1105-3374-94f6-4c6f21406756
2020-03-16 11:28:22.616  INFO 19392 --- [           main] faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named 'errorChannel' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default PublishSubscribeChannel will be created.
2020-03-16 11:28:22.620  INFO 19392 --- [           main] faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named 'taskScheduler' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default ThreadPoolTaskScheduler will be created.
2020-03-16 11:28:22.622  INFO 19392 --- [           main] faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default DefaultHeaderChannelRegistry will be created.
2020-03-16 11:28:22.661  INFO 19392 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'integrationChannelResolver' of type [org.springframework.integration.support.channel.BeanFactoryChannelResolver] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-03-16 11:28:22.667  INFO 19392 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'integrationDisposableAutoCreatedBeans' of type [org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.Disposables] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-03-16 11:28:22.676  INFO 19392 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.IntegrationManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.integration.config.IntegrationManagementConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-03-16 11:28:22.678  INFO 19392 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.integration.IntegrationAutoConfiguration$IntegrationJmxConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.integration.IntegrationAutoConfiguration$IntegrationJmxConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-03-16 11:28:22.683  INFO 19392 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jmx.JmxAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jmx.JmxAutoConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-03-16 11:28:22.686  INFO 19392 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'mbeanServer' of type [com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-03-16 11:28:22.855  INFO 19392 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8888 (http)
2020-03-16 11:28:22.861  INFO 19392 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-03-16 11:28:22.861  INFO 19392 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.31]
2020-03-16 11:28:22.960  INFO 19392 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-03-16 11:28:22.960  INFO 19392 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1149 ms
2020-03-16 11:28:23.358  INFO 19392 --- [           main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Initializing ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
2020-03-16 11:28:23.577  INFO 19392 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-03-16 11:28:24.839  INFO 19392 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.core.DefaultCredentialsProvider  : Default credentials provider for service account spring-samples-service-account@spring-samples-269912.iam.gserviceaccount.com
2020-03-16 11:28:24.839  INFO 19392 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.core.DefaultCredentialsProvider  : Scopes in use by default credentials: [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spanner.admin, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spanner.data, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.admin, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudruntimeconfig, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-vision, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery]
2020-03-16 11:28:24.839  INFO 19392 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.a.c.GcpContextAutoConfiguration  : The default project ID is spring-samples-269912
2020-03-16 11:28:24.846  INFO 19392 --- [           main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Initializing ExecutorService 'pubsubPublisherThreadPool'
2020-03-16 11:28:24.847  INFO 19392 --- [           main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Initializing ExecutorService 'pubsubSubscriberThreadPool'
2020-03-16 11:28:24.864  INFO 19392 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'pubSubAcknowledgementExecutor'
2020-03-16 11:28:25.231  INFO 19392 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2020-03-16 11:28:25.276  INFO 19392 --- [           main] o.s.c.s.m.DirectWithAttributesChannel    : Channel 'application-1.springCloudBusInput' has 1 subscriber(s).
2020-03-16 11:28:25.328  INFO 19392 --- [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Registering MessageChannel springCloudBusOutput
2020-03-16 11:28:25.368  INFO 19392 --- [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Registering MessageChannel springCloudBusInput
2020-03-16 11:28:25.374  INFO 19392 --- [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Registering MessageChannel errorChannel
2020-03-16 11:28:25.395  INFO 19392 --- [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Registering MessageChannel nullChannel
2020-03-16 11:28:25.405  INFO 19392 --- [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Registering MessageHandler org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerMessageHandler@77e6053
2020-03-16 11:28:25.439  INFO 19392 --- [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Registering MessageHandler errorLogger
2020-03-16 11:28:25.457  INFO 19392 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
2020-03-16 11:28:25.457  INFO 19392 --- [           main] o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : Channel 'application-1.errorChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2020-03-16 11:28:25.457  INFO 19392 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger'
```

thread dump looks like this:

[image]

What do I wrong ?

### P.S.

After very long await I was able see following:

```
2020-03-16 11:49:46.163 ERROR 17324 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService  : Failed to create producer binding; retrying in 30 seconds

org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.BinderException: Exception thrown while building outbound endpoint
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:240) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:90) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractBinder.bindProducer(AbstractBinder.java:152) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.doBindProducer(BindingService.java:296) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindProducer(BindingService.java:271) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindableProxyFactory.createAndBindOutputs(AbstractBindableProxyFactory.java:136) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle.doStartWithBindable(OutputBindingLifecycle.java:58) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedValues.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:608) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindingLifecycle.start(AbstractBindingLifecycle.java:57) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle.start(OutputBindingLifecycle.java:34) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:360) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:158) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:122) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:894) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at root_pack.ServerApplication.main(ServerApplication.java:12) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnavailableException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: Credentials failed to obtain metadata
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:69) ~[gax-1.49.1.jar:1.49.1]
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:72) ~[gax-grpc-1.49.1.jar:1.49.1]
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:60) ~[gax-grpc-1.49.1.jar:1.49.1]
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable$ExceptionTransformingFuture.onFailure(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:97) ~[gax-grpc-1.49.1.jar:1.49.1]
    at com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:68) ~[api-common-1.8.1.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:982) ~[guava-28.1-android.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:30) ~[guava-28.1-android.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1138) ~[guava-28.1-android.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:957) ~[guava-28.1-android.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:748) ~[guava-28.1-android.jar:na]
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$GrpcFuture.setException(ClientCalls.java:515) ~[grpc-stub-1.24.1.jar:1.24.1]
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:490) ~[grpc-stub-1.24.1.jar:1.24.1]
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39) ~[grpc-api-1.24.1.jar:1.24.1]
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23) ~[grpc-api-1.24.1.jar:1.24.1]
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40) ~[grpc-api-1.24.1.jar:1.24.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.CensusStatsModule$StatsClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusStatsModule.java:700) ~[grpc-core-1.24.1.jar:1.24.1]
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39) ~[grpc-api-1.24.1.jar:1.24.1]
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23) ~[grpc-api-1.24.1.jar:1.24.1]
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40) ~[grpc-api-1.24.1.jar:1.24.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.CensusTracingModule$TracingClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusTracingModule.java:399) ~[grpc-core-1.24.1.jar:1.24.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:510) ~[grpc-core-1.24.1.jar:1.24.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:66) ~[grpc-core-1.24.1.jar:1.24.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:630) ~[grpc-core-1.24.1.jar:1.24.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$700(ClientCallImpl.java:518) ~[grpc-core-1.24.1.jar:1.24.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:692) ~[grpc-core-1.24.1.jar:1.24.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:681) ~[grpc-core-1.24.1.jar:1.24.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37) ~[grpc-core-1.24.1.jar:1.24.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123) ~[grpc-core-1.24.1.jar:1.24.1]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
    Suppressed: com.google.api.gax.rpc.AsyncTaskException: Asynchronous task failed
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptions.callAndTranslateApiException(ApiExceptions.java:57) ~[gax-1.49.1.jar:1.49.1]
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnaryCallable.call(UnaryCallable.java:112) ~[gax-1.49.1.jar:1.49.1]
        at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.TopicAdminClient.getTopic(TopicAdminClient.java:518) ~[google-cloud-pubsub-1.101.0.jar:1.101.0]
        at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.TopicAdminClient.getTopic(TopicAdminClient.java:473) ~[google-cloud-pubsub-1.101.0.jar:1.101.0]
        at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.pubsub.PubSubAdmin.getTopic(PubSubAdmin.java:121) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.stream.binder.pubsub.provisioning.PubSubChannelProvisioner.makeSureTopicExists(PubSubChannelProvisioner.java:118) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-stream-binder-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.stream.binder.pubsub.provisioning.PubSubChannelProvisioner.provisionProducerDestination(PubSubChannelProvisioner.java:63) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-stream-binder-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.stream.binder.pubsub.provisioning.PubSubChannelProvisioner.provisionProducerDestination(PubSubChannelProvisioner.java:45) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-stream-binder-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:222) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:90) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractBinder.bindProducer(AbstractBinder.java:152) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.doBindProducer(BindingService.java:296) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindProducer(BindingService.java:271) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindableProxyFactory.createAndBindOutputs(AbstractBindableProxyFactory.java:136) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle.doStartWithBindable(OutputBindingLifecycle.java:58) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
        at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedValues.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:608) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindingLifecycle.start(AbstractBindingLifecycle.java:57) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle.start(OutputBindingLifecycle.java:34) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:360) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:158) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:122) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:894) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at root_pack.ServerApplication.main(ServerApplication.java:12) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: Credentials failed to obtain metadata
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:533) ~[grpc-api-1.24.1.jar:1.24.1]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error getting access token for service account: 400 Bad Request
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid JWT Signature."}
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.refreshAccessToken(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:432) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.18.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.refresh(OAuth2Credentials.java:157) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.18.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.getRequestMetadata(OAuth2Credentials.java:145) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.18.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.auth.Credentials.blockingGetToCallback(Credentials.java:112) ~[google-auth-library-credentials-0.18.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.auth.Credentials$1.run(Credentials.java:98) ~[google-auth-library-credentials-0.18.0.jar:na]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid JWT Signature."}
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1097) ~[google-http-client-1.32.1.jar:1.32.1]
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.refreshAccessToken(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:429) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.18.0.jar:na]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Hi @gstackoverflow , were you able to fix this issue?

Comment: any fix for this yet?